# CSS Horizontal space div table

Tags: html, css, uitableview, css-tables

I'm working on a div table in CSS. What I'm trying to do is to set the same space between margins and table cells and between table cells.

This is what I want to achieve:

[image: Maked white paint]

But this is what it currently looks like:

[image: Table result]

I'm using this code for the class:

```
 .tfoto{width:600px;
        display:table;
        margin-left:200px;
        border-top-style:dotted;
        border-bottom-style:dotted;
        border-left-style:dotted;
        border-right-style:dotted;
        text-align:center;

        background-color:transparent;
        border-spacing:1px;
        collapse:separate;}

.tcaption {display:table-caption;
           font:"Traditional Arabic";}

.trow {display:table-row;
       width:200px;
       cell-spacing:5px;
       padding:5px;}

.tdcell {display:table-cell;
         width:200px;
         padding:5px;}
```

Comment: Please Update the HTML Code you are trying

Comment: @deajoe plz add html code you working with

Comment: Look up here for the codes: https://jsfiddle.net/w3n5kc7c/

Comment: It's because you've used table width of 600px. The table makes the cells 300px wide (600/2 (columns)). [Here's your modified code](https://jsfiddle.net/mrubpb99/)

Comment: Use `border-spacing`, see my answer.

Comment: @oboer thanks! I was no longer looking for the 'width:' property, it solve the issue

Comment: @Deanjoe you had 2 syntax errors, if you fix those 2, you'll fix it perfectly. See update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set Class

```
.imgs{
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
}
```

Checkout This :

```css
.tfoto{width:600px;
        display:table;
        margin-left:200px;
        border-top-style:dotted;
        border-bottom-style:dotted;
        border-left-style:dotted;
        border-right-style:dotted;
        text-align:center;

        background-color:transparent;
        border-spacing:1px;
        collapse:separate;}

.tcaption {display:table-caption;
           font:"Traditional Arabic";}

.trow {display:table-row;
       width:200px;
       cell-spacing:5px;
       padding:5px;}

.tdcell {display:table-cell;
         width:200px;
         padding:5px;}
 .imgs {width:100%;
      height:200px;}
```

```html
<div class="tfoto">
  <div class="tcaption">
   <p><em>Sample text.</em></p> 
  </div>
  <div class="trow">
  <div class="tdcell">
  <img class="imgs" src="foto1.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="tdcell">
  <img class="imgs" src="foto2.jpg">
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="trow">
  <div class="tdcell">
  <img class="imgs" src="foto3.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="tdcell">
  <img class="imgs" src="foto4.jpg">
  </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## UPDATE

It looks like you were very close, but you had 2 crucial syntax errors, see Snippet 2:

```
       collapse:separate;
```

**AND**

```
       cell-spacing:5px;
```

**Should be:**

```
        border-collapse:separate;
```

**AND**

```
        border-spacing:5px
```

Now it looks exactly as you wanted it.

---

Use [`border-spacing`](http://quirksmode.org/css/css2/tables.html)

#### SNIPPET 1

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-spacing: 5px;
  outline: 5px solid #fff;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
td {
  outline: 5px solid #fff;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

#### SNIPPET 2

```css
.tfoto {
  width: 600px;
  display: table;
  margin-left: 200px;
  border-top-style: dotted;
  border-bottom-style: dotted;
  border-left-style: dotted;
  border-right-style: dotted;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-spacing: 1px;
  border-collapse: separate;
}
.tcaption {
  display: table-caption;
  font: "Traditional Arabic";
}
.trow {
  display: table-row;
  width: 200px;
  border-spacing: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.tdcell {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.imgs {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tfoto">
  <div class="tcaption">
    <p><em>Sample text.</em>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="trow">
    <div class="tdcell">
      <img class="imgs" src="foto1.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="tdcell">
      <img class="imgs" src="foto2.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="trow">
    <div class="tdcell">
      <img class="imgs" src="foto3.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="tdcell">
      <img class="imgs" src="foto4.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: It works for a table in HTML but there are two points to fix: 
1) The images are not set for the entire cell space;

Comment: The images are responsive or fixed? If the latter, what are their dimensions?